# Breaking network links without creating orphans?

Tags: netlogo

I have a grid of 10x10 nodes where all adjacent nodes are linked to create a graph of 180 links - i.e:

[image]

What I hope to do is create a procedure which will break x% of these links, but importantly do so without creating any isolated subgraphs - that is, so that any 1 of the 100 nodes remain accessible from all other 99 nodes - i.e.

[image]

I initially (and naively) thought I could do something like the following:

```
ask n-of 45 nodes with [count my-links > 1] 
[
    ask one-of my-links [die]
]
```

However, this does not prevent sub-graphs from being orphaned from the main graph - i.e.

[image]

Another option might be to repeatedly ask single links to die and then check the total number of graphs does not exceed 1 - if it does, recreate the link and choose another to break. However, (1) this does not seem particularly elegant; and (2) I have been unable to find a way to count the number of distinct graphs using the inbuilt link or nw procedures.

I do think that part of my problem is not knowing the correct terminology for these subgraphs/isolates/cliques etc...

If anyone has any ideas on how this might be done (or can correct my woefully inadequate comprehension of graph theory terminology) it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution you thought of, you can use the `nw` extension to check if there's still a path between the nodes you just disconnected by checking if [`nw:distance-to`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#distance-to-weighted-distance-to) returns false or a number.

Alternatively, you can count the number of [connected components](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#weak-component-clusters).

I think removing the link and testing connectedness is a perfectly reasonable way to go. Any algorithm you implement will have to awkwardly pretend the link doesn't exist anyway, so will likely be more complicated than just removing the thing.

Edit: Adding code for the distance version to clarify:

```
to break-link
  let break-candidate one-of links
  let end-one [end1] of break-candidate
  let end-two [end2] of break-candidate
  ask break-candidate [die]
  if [nw:distance-to end-two] of end-one = false [
    ask end-one [ create-link-with end-two ]
    break-link
  ]
end
```

Not sure if this or the `nw:weak-component-cluster` version will be faster. That will likely depend on the size of the network.

Comment: If you use the `nw:distance-to` approach, it would be very inefficient to test to all other nodes, but picking a specific node (eg A) would only guarantee the network remains connected if you test both ends of the break. For example, if you break the link B to C, then you need to check both the BA distance and the CA distance to guarantee connectedness. A different approach would be to break as many links as you like and then rewire to join components. This would need fewer tests but rewiring would be difficult: you need two nodes next to each other in different components.

Comment: Oh, my suggestion was to break the link between A and B, and then check the distance from A to B. If breaking a link creates a new component, then the two endpoints of the former link are guaranteed to be in different components. Thanks for making me clarify though.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for the heads-up re nw:weak-component-clusters - I wasn't aware of that.

I have now implemented the following simple recursive procedure which will kill a link and if that link splits the graph recreate it and recall the procedure. This works well for what I wanted to do. Do note however that if you run this enough times you will end up stuck in a recursive loop as there will be no further links to break without splitting the graph and the procedure will keep calling itself.

```
to breakLink
  let breakCandidate one-of links  
  let end1Candidate [end1] of breakCandidate 
  let end2Candidate [end2] of breakCandidate 

  ask breakCandidate [die]
  if (length nw:weak-component-clusters > 1) 
  [ 
    ask end1Candidate 
    [
      create-link-with end2Candidate 
      breakLink
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `nw:set-context` here. Since `links` is a link breed (the default link breed), the context updates automatically as links are created and destroyed. In fact, if you find that you do need to use `nw:set-context`, chances are you've found a bug and should let me know!